# Llamada múltiple a servicio Web Api

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Tengo el método `ObtenerInfoPersona()` que obtiene una lista de personas y llamada a una api (Method:Post) por cada persona obtenida.

Antiguamente se procesaba rápido porque la lista de personas retornaba 10 a 60 personas pero ahora retorna mas de 100 y eso hace que demore el proceso.

Tengo la clase Persona

```
public class Persona{ 
     public int Id {get;set;}  
     public string Nombre{ get;set;} 
}
```

El metodo que trae la lista de personas y donde llama el método del API

```
public void ObtenerInfoPersona(){
List<Persona> lstPersona = new List<Persona>()
lstPersona = objData.ObtenerPersonasDiarias();//Puede devolver mas de 1k de registros 

foreach(var p in lstPersona){
     var result = API(p);
}
```

}

y la llamada del api se realiza de este modo

```
public async Task<string> API(Persona persona)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona);
    var requestData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format(urlApi), requestData);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result; //retorna status 
 }
}
```

Comment: 1. La API es tuya?
1.1 Si es asi, puedes mostrar el endpoint para obtener las personas?
1.2 Si no es asi, no puedes hacer nada ya que el endpoint al que consultas esta configurado para que retorne todos los datos.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema que veo es que la api deberia recibir un listado de personas a procesar y devolverte el resultado, y no llamar a la api 100 veces o mas. Si en tu caso no puedes modificar la api porque no esta en tu control, lo que deberias realizar es un llamado en paralelo y de esa forma tu rendimiento sera muy superior al que tienes hoy aunque vuelvas a trabajar con 40 o 60 registros.

Para realizar un recorrido en paralelo de tu Lista podes usar la clase Parallel, esa clase crea tantos hilos como el S.O. le permite, con el metodo Foreach.

```
public void ObtenerInfoPersona()
{
  List<Persona> lstPersona = new List<Persona>();
  lstPersona = objData.ObtenerPersonasDiarias();//Puede devolver mas de 1k de registros 

  Parallel.ForEach(lstPersona, (persona) =>
  {
    var result = API(persona);
  });
}
```

[Documentacion de Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0)